# rkhunter reports hidden TCP port (probably NFS server)

Tags: 16.04, server, kernel, nfs

After upgrading my server from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS the rkhunter nightly report complains about a hidden TCP port. The port number changes if I reboot the server and the port number is always below 1023. Scanning with unhide-tcp also reveals that it takes a few minutes after reboot before it shows up.

Googling the problem led me to this post: http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg910866.html

The description of the problem matches mine perfectly, and disabling the nfs-server.service removes the problem. The code in question seems to have been rewritten, but the problem still exists.

I also tried to update the kernel to v4.8 from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8/, and the problem still persisted.

This is a major pain, since I either have to disable hidden port scan from rkhunter, or I have to make a white list in rkhunter.conf which must be updated every time a new port shows up hidden.

Has anyone else come across this problem, and found a solution or feasible workaround?

Comment: What service(s) are listening on the port(s) in question? If they are the RPC `statd` and/or `mountd` services, it used to be possible to specify fixed ports for these via `/etc/default/*` - I'm not sure how it's done now since 16.04 uses `systemd`, but that might give you a starting point.

Comment: Determine which process has the port (`port#`) open: `sudo lsof -i tcp:port#`.

Comment: That's the point with hidden ports - it will not show up in ss/netstat/lsof. If you read the details and answers in the link I provided, you see that it's the NFS kernel code that closes the port that causes this.